# I can't use import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory; even though I installed it in build.gradle

Tags: jackson2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKAot.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6zuy.png)

I installed it in build.gradle but it doesn't work. I found some answers but they don't work for me, for example :implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:1.15.0-rc'. I am using android studio version 23.1.2